# How use Videos from another directory?

Tags: media-library, videos

I have a huge number of videos on my server in the folder of root directory. As they have a large size I do not want to upload them to "Media Library" one by one.

How can I say to Wordpress to use the videos from that directory, and also to see them listed in Media Library->Video.

Comment: You should use probably use a service like YouTube or Vimeo for this. If you must use your server to host your videos, a mass upload via the latest media uploaded is even safer than regular FTP, and should work at the similar speeds.

Answer (score 0):

However you can create plugin for that. From admin end, you can specify the folder path. From there videos can be loaded in your site. That's all. You have to write all video supported format.

Comment: This answer does not make sense.

Comment: I do not want to use any service like YouTube. And also I do not want to move them. I just want to say Wordpress in some way to use this Video folder in  "Media Library".